# How does const auto and auto const apply to pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was try out some code and am wondering how the `const` qualifier in C++ applies to pointer types when using `auto`.

```
int main()
{
  int foo = 1;
  int bar = 2;

  //Expected: const int * ptr_to_const_int = &foo;
  const auto ptr_to_const_int = &foo;

  //Expected: int * const const_ptr_to_int = &foo;
  auto const const_ptr_to_int = &foo;


  *ptr_to_const_int = 3; //Thought this would error
  //ptr_to_const_int = &bar; This does error.
  *const_ptr_to_int = 3;

  return 0;
}
```

I realize there is a similar question asking if they are the same, I am asking more specifically what is the rule here that is getting applied to the deduction of the end pointer type.

Comment: It works for aliases in a same way: `using T = int *; const T` -> `int *const`.

Comment: `const auto` and `auto const` will be the same type. [Example](https://godbolt.org/g/EsNB52)

Comment: [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) uses the rules for [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this example, `const` is being applied to whatever `auto` deduces, which means both uses result in an object of type `int * const`, because `auto` on its own is deducing `int *`. The ordering that you're imagining takes place based on whether you write it `auto const` or `const auto` doesn't happen, in the same way that `int const` and `const int` are the same.

An easier way to think about this might be to try the following:

```
template<typename T>
using pointer = T*;

pointer<int> ptr_to_int = new int;
const pointer<int> const_ptr_to_int = new int;
pointer<const int> ptr_to_const_int = new int;
const pointer<const int> const_ptr_to_const_int = new int;

pointer<int> const const_ptr_to_int2 = new int;
pointer<int const> ptr_to_const_int2 = new int;
pointer<const int> const const_ptr_to_const_int2 = new int;

pointer<int const> const const_ptr_to_const_int3 = new int;
```

Any variables in this example, whose names only differ due to appended numbers, are equivalent types, as far as C++ is concerned. Note how changing where the `const` appears doesn't affect the deduced type. This is because the "read-right-to-left" rule for working out how types are declared is based on how raw types are written: once you use constructions like this (or, as you observed, `auto`) the rules become a lot simpler.

My instinct is that, since your problem sort of implies that you need this kind of fine-grained control over the type system anyways, you should use a `using` or `typedef` on `pointer<T>` like I've showcased here, and use that to declare your types, since it's a lot easier to know, at a glance, what `const pointer<int>` is than it is to see what `int *const` is. Especially since it prevents silly mistakes like this:

```
int * a_ptr, b_ptr, c_ptr; //Oops! We meant b_ptr and c_ptr to also be pointers, but
//they ended up being regular ints!

pointer<int> a_ptr, b_ptr, c_ptr; //All of these are pointers, as we expected them to be
```

`auto` technically solves this problem too, but as you're showing in your example, it's still ambiguous (to you) whether the `const` is being applied to the pointer itself, or the object it's pointing to, whereas in this case, there's no more ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

Place matters when there is `*` !!.

1. Placing `const` before `*` makes value const.
2. Placing `const` after  `*` makes addr  const.
3. Placing `const` before/after `*` makes both value and addr const.

I have given a few possible combination of `auto`, `const` and `*` usage for better understanding.

```
    int main() {
        auto i = 2;               // int
        const auto j = 10;        // const int  
        
        // j = 20;                // Error: value is const

        const auto a = &i;        // int * const
        // a = &j;                // Error: addr is const
        *a = 4;                   // OK (value is NOT const)

        const auto* b = &i;       // const int *
        // *b = 4;                // Error: value is const
        b = &j;                   // OK (addr is NOT const)

        auto* const c = &i;       // const int *
        *c = 4;                   // OK (value is NOT const)
        // c = &j;                // Error: addr is const

        const auto* const d = &i; // const int * const
        // *d = 4;                // Error: Both value & addr are const
        // d = &j;                // Error: Both value & addr are const
    }
```